# Powershell script and outputting to file share

Tags: powershell, permissions, fileshare

I have a powershell script that is converting CSV to XLSX.  It works as intended when outputting to local disk.  It runs for a few seconds and then an XLSX file is generated in $files path.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\test\*.csv
Write "Loading Files..."

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

ForEach ($file in $files)
{

     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilepath = $file.Fullname -replace ".{4}$"
     $NewFilepath =  $NewFilepath + ".xlsx"
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,51)
}

$Excel.Quit()  
Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
```

But when I change it to output to a file share, it immediately completes with no error, but no output file is generated.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem \\fileserver\path\*.csv
Write "Loading Files..."

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

ForEach ($file in $files)
{

     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilepath = $file.Fullname -replace ".{4}$"
     $NewFilepath =  $NewFilepath + ".xlsx"
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,51)
}

$Excel.Quit()  
Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
```

I would suspect this is a permissions issue, but the logged in account has write access the share.  Does a powershell script change the user/account context?  What can I add to this script to capture errors and identify the problem?

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong path on the file share.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "\\fileserver\path" -filter *.csv"
```

and then separately echo out after your $NewFilepath assignments.

If that doesn't give you more info, then try writing something simple to the share like:

```
"Hello World" > "\\fileserver\path\test.txt"
```

That could give you clues on user context and permissions.